# ms access 2003 random record within join

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I am trying to get a random record from a join, but I cannot get it to work! Any ideas? It's using Microsoft Access 2003.

```
table = members
===============
memberID int
name varchar

table = testimonials
====================
testimonialID int
memberID int
content memo

select m.*, (SELECT t.content from testimonials t where t.memberID=m.memberID ORDER BY rnd(t.testimonialID)) as testimonialtext
FROM members m;
```

I basically need each member record and one random testimonial for that member. I should also add that I've tried it within a join too...

```
select m.*, t.content FROM members m
INNER JOIN testimonials t ON m.memberID=t.memberID
ORDER BY rnd(t.testimonialID)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what exactly does not work? the records are multiplying?

Comment: The first query returns "Invalid Memo, OLE or Hyperlink Object in subquery 't.content'". It's a memo field not text as above. Not sure how to solve that one!!

Comment: does the second query returns anything? or also procudes the error?

Comment: the second one just produces a list with duplicated values and unique testimonial content. Its one member to many testimonials. I need to some how limit each member to one RANDOM testimonial. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not change your method to choose a random MemberID and then use that in your criteria to return the content for that MemberID? I for one remain baffled at the number of SO questions involving returning random records -- I've been programming professionally in Access since 1996 and have never once needed to return a random record for any purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to limit with TOP clause

```
select m.*, (SELECT top 1 t.content from testimonials t where t.memberID=m.memberID ORDER BY rnd(t.testimonialID)) as testimonialtext
FROM members m;
```

ok, then we can do something like:

```
select 
  m.*, 
  t3.content
FROM 
  members m, 
   (select 
      top 1 t.testimonialID, 
    from 
      testimonials t 
    where 
      t.memberID=m.memberID 
    order by 
      rnd(t.testimonialID)
    ) t2,
   testimonials t3 
where
  t3.testimonialID = t2.testimonialID;
```

Comment: thanks... that still produces the Invalid memo field error though (as above comment)

Comment: The help from MS Access says "A subquery cannot return a Memo or OLE Object, and it cannot be compared to a Memo or OLE Object in an expression"

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. I did manage to get it working by using left(t.content,10000) - not sure if that is good or not though!!